# Getting the result of union all without having to copy an entire query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to list all months of 2016 and 2017, to do this I use the good old UNION ALL

```
select *
from year2016
  join months on months.year_id = year2016.id

union all

select *
from year2017
  join months on months.year_id = year2017.id
```

It works as expected but if I join another table, I have to duplicate in both queries

Is there a better way to do this?
Something like:

```
select *
from year2016, year2017
  join months on months.year_id in(year2016.id, year2017.id)
```

My database is postgresql 9.4 but I believe it will be at least interesting for other databases as well.

[EDIT]

As Gordon Linoff pointed I was just selecting from months, but that's not the idea, so now it selects everything

Comment: Nope, your first query is correct. You are `UNION` data from two different tables.

Comment: But your table `year2016` looks weird. what data you have there?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it's just an example, in reality I have a table partitioned by day, so I have to query the records inserted in the last 18 hours, so if it's less than 18:00 I need to query the day before. Some queries have about 100 lines without UNION, and since the other query is identical, except for the day (day1, day2, day3 .... day31), I thought I could reduce it's length...

Comment: If you have multiple tables for same data, you probably should use [**INHERITANCE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-inheritance.html)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza A good suggestion, but keep in mind if he uses table-per-type inheritance pattern, then queries across base type still require a union across the concrete type tables.

Comment: @AaronLS Not sure what you mean, in the sample show on the link explain how convert one `UNION` view to inheritance sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```
select m.*
from months m
where exists (select 1 from year2016 y where y.id = m.year_id) or
      exists (select 1 from year2017 y where y.id = m.year_id);
```

If you are only selecting from the `months` table, there are other approaches beyond `union`.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports common table expressions,

- Wrap your initial union in a CTE with clause
- Reference the CTE name in one side of the join in a query following the CTE.

They are a great way to express your query in a way that it is clear what each layer of the query accomplishes, and you can even run the CTE by itself and slowly add the additional CTEs in order to test intermediate steps.  Much better in my opinion than nested queries in terms of readability, testability, and easier for future devs to wrap there head around them.  It also allows you to comment each CTE in order for future devs to more easily grasp what each step does.  The performance penalty should be negligible(in other DBMS's it is), but I am not an expert on Postgre and can't say that for sure.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: I dont think `CTE` is the problem, OP want use a different sintaxis instead of `UNION`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza "if I join another table, I have to duplicate in both queries" I am addressing this, by allowing him to avoid duplicating the join, and instead join against the result of the union.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you have in tables `year2016, year2017`. My guess is those are constants.

So you could do something like

```
SELECT months.*
FROM months
WHERE month.year_id IN (2016,2017)
```